# Create Workflow that will send a mail with field Exception condition - Don't send mail when specific field is changeing

Tags: workflow

[image]
I'm trying to create Workflow that will support any modification in a list but will ignore change in specific field.
the field is a status field that i have in it 4 option in a drop down list

**strong text**
There is not If not condition that i can exclude this field out

Appreciate the help
Thanks 
Almog

Comment: So if a user makes a change to the status field you don't want that change to save? Are there any exceptions to this, as I am confused what you want exactly?

Comment: If the status field will change the workflow will not send a mail - only if it done for all other fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i success to do it in the same workflow see below the pic i just post 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since SharePoint workflows are asynchronous in nature (runs after item updated in content DB), you don't have any direct means to check which field was updated.

But as a work around, you can use the following logic.

1. Create new columns for all columns you dont want to execute the Send Mail (for example create a new column Status_WF). Make sure it is not visible to users.
2. In your workflow, check the condition `if CurerntItem:Status equals CurrentItem:Status_WF`, than execute the logic, i.e. send mail (since status is not changed, that means, other fields changed, expand to multiple check if you have more than one field)
3. Now create another if block, with condition `CurrentItem:Status not equals CurrentItem:Status_WF`, than update the Status_WF column with Status column value (your status column changed here, add multiple check if you have more thanone field).

This way you can track, if the specified column is update or not.

**Edit**

My workflow is a list item level workflow, automatically triggers on Item Created or Changed. You can check the [workflow working in this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7CIEvKriINsM0o5ZV8xUzlXeHc/view?usp=sharing) (Please download the video for better quality view).

The workflow looks like following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, When i create the Column status_WF in the 1st place do i need to create it with the 4 options i have in it?(New/WIP/Complete/Reject)

Comment: and how the workflow will know that there is difference if no one physically pick an option from it

Comment: Not working-  still sending 2 mails. 1 for modification and 1 for status change (have another workflow that check status change only) - can you please detailed it

Comment: I made an edit to ans. You can check now.

Comment: Thanks, but i tried it several times and it still not work for me, is there another way to process it? or is there a way you can help me in a private session?

Comment: If you can tell me exactly what you want to achieve may be i can suggest something better

Comment: I want to have 1 workflow for any modification that is been done in the form and will ignore the Status column change. So if someone will change the status column it will not send any mail

Comment: The above logic is doing exactly what you want. But instead of sending mail, I am console logging. `Other Column Change`  is the case when you want to send mail. Other if block execute when `Status` column change.

Comment: OK, but it's not working for me, is there a way you can create it for me and i will copy paste it into my workflow? or is there a way we can meet somehow and you will help me with that, thanks almog

Comment: I'll suggest you start with basic concept first. First start with checking if you can track status change by using `workflow log to history` action.

Comment: you can scan my profile and find my twitter handle.

Comment: OK, I success to create the Status change workflow that will send mail only when status field is changed. Now i want to create another Workflow that will send a mail to any modification without the status how should i do that

Comment: In the same workflow, try to add another condition which is just opposite of above condition. i.e. if you are checking for Status change than check for Status not change and log to history first. If you can achieve that, than add rest of the logic.

Comment: Can you help me with the written of this workflow -thanks

Comment: Sure, you can find my twitter handle in profile. Contact me there. I'll have a close look on what you are doing and where you are failing.