# SharePoint 2007 - On Change Workflow Individual Field - Send Email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, 2007

I have a list with about 20 fields.

One of the fields is a hidden choice field called 'Approved or Rejected?'. Once the form has been submitted, the admin of the list will need to go in and either approve or reject the submission.

Once a decision has been made, the creator will need to get an email saying that 'Your submission has been 'Approved/Rejected'.

How would I go about creating this so that an email is only sent when that individual field is changed?

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221145/create-workflow-that-will-send-a-mail-with-field-exception-condition-dont-sen/221175

Answer (score 0):

You will have to maintain the previous value of hidden choice (e.g. Prev_Status) field. In SPD workflow, on edit item change, compare the Prev_Status and Status field to find if any change has happened.

If yes, send mail.
If no, exit workflow.