# Workflow to send mail based on the change of value for one field in the list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

How to make the Workflow to send mail based on the change of value for one field in the list and when the item is created first.

When the item is created the mail can be sent, I can see the option but for the change of the value of one field (only) I want to trigger mail again.

Please assist.

Comment: Check this post. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221145/create-workflow-that-will-send-a-mail-with-field-exception-condition-dont-sen